# How to compare directory stucture on 2 hosts

Tags: linux, file, networking, copy

I'm installing perl modules from cpan.org on one linux host. They all drop down in some folders.

**1. I need to figure out, where do the drop down.**
2. I need to copy these files and folders to the second host over the network.

Let's assume that the directory "/" stucture of both hosts is identical before installation of perl modules.

How can I do it a simple way?

Thank you.

Comment: It depends on how you install the module. Look here for advice: http://www.cpan.org/modules/INSTALL.html